# How can I find the files that will be included by a cq:includeClientLib tag?

Tags: jsp, tags, adobe, aem

I am working on JSPs in Adobe CQ5.  In one of the JSPs that I am not very familiar with, there is a CQ **[includeClientLib](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/howto/taglib.html#%3Ccq%3aincludeClientLib%3E)** tag that includes a CQ client library onto the page:

```
<cq:includeClientLib categories="someCategory"/>
```

**How can I determine/find all the files that will be included by this reference?**  Essentially, I need to find all the cq:ClientLibraryFolder nodes in the CQ repository that have a "categories" property defined with a value of "someCategory."  I have done searches in Content Explorer and CRXDE Lite, but these find all matches for "someCategory" even if they aren't ClientLibraryFolders that have been tagged with the "categories" property, and in my case there are simply too many false-positives to sift through manually.  So I am looking for a way to filter the matches to only those that are included by this tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a list of all of the client library information by going to the UR http://&HOST%:%PORT%/libs/cq/ui/content/dumplibs.html of your target CQ instance. Scroll down to the 'Libraries by Category' section to see all of the cq:ClientLibraryFolder paths that use each category.

Example: http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/ui/content/dumplibs.html